# If B and C are subsets of Y, then prove $f^{-1}(C/B)=f^{-1}(C)/f^{-1}(B)$

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Important to note that $B$ and $C$ are subsets of $Y$ where $f: X \to Y$

This appears to be a direct proof $$y \in f^{-1}(C/B)$$
implies that $$y \in f^{-1}(C)$$ and $$y \notin f^{-1}(B)$$
Therefore $$y \in f^{-1}(C)/f^{-1}(B)$$

Of course this must be proved backwards as well:

$$y \in f^{-1}(C)/f^{-1}(B)$$

implies

$$y \in f^{-1}(C), y \notin f^{-1}(B)$$

$$y \in f^{-1}(C/B)$$

The proof may need to be cleaned up but is the logic sound?

Comment: $$y \in f^{-1}(C \setminus B) \iff f(y) \in C \setminus B \iff f(y) \in C \text{ and } f(y) \not\in B.$$

Comment: Also, this has been asked multiple times on this site. Please check approach0.xyz before asking a question, i.e. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178918/let-f-x-rightarrow-y-be-a-function-and-a-subseteq-y-and-b-subseteq-y).

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. $x \in f^{-1}[C\setminus B]$ ( notice the `\setminus` symbol for set difference, forward slash `/` is for quotients! ) iff $f(x) \in C \setminus B$ iff $f(x) \in C$ and $f(x) \notin B$ iff $x \in f^{-1}[C]$ and $x \notin f^{-1}[B]$ iff $x \in f^{-1}[B]\setminus f^{-1}[C]$.

So you need to talk about $x$ (as the sets live in the domain) and its image $f(x)$, not $y$, that's confusing. We repeatedly use the definition $f^{-1}[A] = \{x \in X: f(x) \in A\}$, plus the definition of set difference. In the above sequence of iff statements, as an exercise, state next to each equivalence to which definition this is due.

Comment: Okay I see what you are saying with x and f(x) so how i do make that flow? Is it okay to show it with iif in my presentation?

Comment: @Oberyn it’s allowed to use iff when you justify it. Your first step e.g. is not reasoned.